# Change Administration Console Password in Jboss

Tags: jboss5.x

How to change Administrator console password using web console
Now i start my Jboss and given the path till default port on Browser,
after that i click on Administration COnsole the it asked me for UserName and Password then i given it, But there is not any option of Change password there,

Then what can i do to change password?

Please tell me the steps

Answer (score 8):

go to jboss installation root directory. And then navigate to bin folder. Launch ./add-user.sh and then type existing user name and after warning the user already exists just type new password.

Answer (score 5):

1.Log in to your server and open the root directory.
2.Open the path "server > default > conf >props/" and look for the "jmx-console-users.properties" file.
3.Open "jmx-console-users.properties" with a text editor such as notepad. You will see a list of user names and passwords in the format of "username=password."
4.Delete the password for the admin console account and type in a new password.
5.Upload the changed file back into the props foloder